# Jackson - how to parse to POJO when you arent sure of the contents (superclass?)

Tags: jackson

I can easily parse/deserialize into my predefined POJOs when I know exactly what is coming in but in the case of this:

```
{
  "pricequote" : {
    "USD" : {
      "price": 2.56
    }
  }
}
```

Now Ive simplified my real data a ton, by taking lots of fields out but that is the basics of it.  where "pricequote" is always the same but depending on the http API I use, I may be requesting EUR, but all the contents returned for either USD/EUR/etc are all the same, everything is always the same except USD/EUR/etc.

So I *guess* this would be super() to work it out?  but cant figure out how to tell super() which one to use.

Comment: I would not use inheritance in your case. It seems to be a rabbit hole here. I would create class `Pricequote` with `String currency` and `double price` properties. To covert it to.from JSON I would create a custom serializer and deserializer. Search for `@JsonDeserialize` and `@JsonSerialize`.

Comment: If you really want to go down the rabbit hole with inheritance for you example search for `@JsonTypeInfo` annotation.